# PHP MYSQL database connection and showing data is not working

Tags: php, mysql

im new to php mysql, need help. Im unable to show data from mysql database through below codes. It shows a blank page :(. can anyone help me please?. below is my config file and index file codes.

config.php

```
<?php
class DB {

    protected $db_name = 'drive';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';


    public function connect() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        return true;
    }


class showClass{
    //USER LIST SHOW function
public function showUser($table){

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE type='user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $data=NULL;
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $data[]=$rows;
            }
            return $data;
        }else{
            echo '<span class="text-info success">No Account Found.</span>';
        exit();
        }

    }

}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'conf/config.php';


$db = new DB();
$db->connect();
$obj_show = new showClass();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drive</title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellpadding="5">

<tr>
<th scope="col"><b>User ID</b></th>
<th scope="col"><b>Name</b></th>
</tr>


<?php

  $allData=$obj_show->showUser("user");
  foreach($allData as $data){
      extract($data);
        echo <<<show

<tr>
  <td>$id</td>
  <td >$username</td>  
</tr>

show;
  }
  ?>

</table>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure... But why your first "new" keyword" starts with a capital letter?
Plus, did you try to make a var_dump() of $db and $obj_show variables after creating them?

Comment: no, how can i do a var_dump() ? please tell

Comment: var_dump($db); var_dump($obj_show); Also, make var_dump($allData) after the line where you assign a value to it. This should help you to analyze the problem.

Comment: if its a blank page, can you check what what is the error display level and add  ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the top of your script and check the output again

Comment: @Cruel_Crow i just tried var_dump($db); and var_dump($obj_show); in index file below the objects, but it doesn't showing anything.

Comment: Also, try this: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: @opensource-ios i just added ini_set('display_errors', 1); and the page is whoing this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\connection\conf\config.php on line 20

Comment: So, here's your problem: you forgot to close your first class with "}".

Comment: make sure `mysql` extension available in your server.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comments already, you're missing **}** after the end of **class DB**.

Answer (score 2):

as @Cruel answer you are missing } at the end of class **DB** try to change

```
class DB {

    protected $db_name = 'drive';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';


    public function connect() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error as shown by your output which got displayed when you added `ini_set function`

The correct code is as below, **you need to add a closing bracket after the class DB**

```
<?php
class DB {

    protected $db_name = 'drive';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';


    public function connect() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        return true;
    }

}// MISSING CLOSING BRACKET
class showClass{
    //USER LIST SHOW function
public function showUser($table){

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE type='user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $data=NULL;
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $data[]=$rows;
            }
            return $data;
        }else{
            echo '<span class="text-info success">No Account Found.</span>';
        exit();
        }

    }

}
```